# Implementation of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, std

How is this implemented:`vector <vector <T> > a;`

Every vector contains an underlying array but to have an array one needs constant size but vector(which is the data-type for outer vector) has variable size. If it is implemented by pointers than how does c++ know when to use pointers and when to use direct values.

Comment: What does this have to do with "vector of vectors"?

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate more about what you are asking? Are you asking how dynamic memory allocation works in C++?

Comment: I have edited it. My question was on how memory is allocated in vector of vectors.

Comment: A vector - does - not - contain - an - array. A vector manages some memory, and it stores elements contiguously in that memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `std::vector<T>` object has a fixed and rather small `sizeof`. It usually contains a *pointer* to an array-of-`T`, the length of that array (its "capacity"), and how much of that array is currently used (the logical size of the vector). Assuming a 64 bit system, these three fields sum up to 8 + 8 + 8 = **24 bytes** and that's your `sizeof(vector<T>)`. Note that this is the same regardless of what `T` is (it could be another vector type, or anything else really) and how many elements the vector stores. When you create a vector (on this platform), be it as a local variable or as element of an array or elsewhere, you allocate only 24 bytes. The allocation for the array happens independently, in some constructor or method of the vector.

The capacity is indeed variable (otherwise vector wouldn't be useful), but that's no problem, we can just allocate it dynamically and make our pointer point at that allocation. The vector object contains only a pointer to the actual storage, regardless.

The reason you can still copy vectors around as if they really contained an arbitrary amount of data as members is that it defines its constructors and other operations to account for that "external" array. For example, when you copy a vector, the copy constructor also creates a new array, copies everything over, and stores a pointer to the new array. In jargon: Each vector has unique ownership of its backing array.

Hence a vector of vectors might look like this in memory:

```
+--------+
| length |
|capacity|
|  data  | ----> +--------+
+--------+       | length |
                 |capacity|
                 |  data  | ----> ...
                 +--------+
                 | length |
                 |capacity|
                 |  data  | ----> ...
                 +--------+
                    ...
```

Comment: I have edited the question. My question was that how does this work when T itself is a vector, how is sizeof determined then?

Comment: @nikhil_vyas I was hoping to make that clear. I edited a bit, please read again and tell me what you think is missing.

Comment: @nikhil_vyas: As stated in this answer `vector` has a fixed size. A `vector` does not directly contain its elements, but rather places them in some memory that it allocates (from the free store, a global data-structure), and then contains a pointer to that memory (and some information about the number of elements in the vector, and the size of the allocated memory).

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are fixed size, and std::vector uses an array, but the implementation will re-allocate the array as necessary.